# JavaScript jQuery Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Hi i have done a code that i need to toggle. How can i do it with this code?

```
    var divh = document.getElementById('first').offsetHeight;

document.getElementById("first").style.height = "100px";

$("div:first").click(function(){
  $("#first").stop().animate({
    height: divh 
  }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: code seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/aErZT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand, you want to toggle height of the div from it's current state to 100px and backward. So why don't you want to use .toggle() method instead?
Like this:

```
//keep default height
var divh = $('#first').outerHeight();

//toggle functions
$('div:first').toggle(
  function () {
     $('#first').stop().animate({
        height: divh +'px'
     }, 1000);
  },
  function () {
    $('#first').stop().animate({
      height: '100px'
    }, 1000);
  }
)
```